# How to filter and drop row based on last max date condition in descending order for loop in python

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to do a for loop where the dataframe is filtered with  max date return from date column  and if the len of rows ==1, then drop and keep on doing that until max date != 1.
Max date here refers to the max date on the date column in dataframe.
The purpose why I am doing a descending here is that because data is appended daily to the dataframe, I am checking the last date if it's returned 1 row only, if so delete so that the append feature from a different function can continue appending from the max date.
The table is like so

| date | names | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | john | 15 |
| 2022-04-01 | jane | 15 |
| 2022-04-01 | Swansa | 15 |
| 2022-04-02 | Timmy | 15 |
| 2022-04-02 | (null) | 15 |
| 2022-04-02 | (null) | 15 |
| 2022-04-03 | (null) | 15 |
| 2022-04-04 | (null) | (null) |
| 2022-04-05 | (null) | (null) |

the expected end results is

| date | names | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | john | 15 |
| 2022-04-01 | jane | 15 |
| 2022-04-01 | Swansa | 15 |
| 2022-04-02 | Timmy | 15 |
| 2022-04-02 | (null) | 15 |
| 2022-04-02 | (null) | 15 |

I have tried doing this

```
latestDate = df['date'].max()
dfRow = len(df[df['date']==latestDate])
if dfRow == 1:
  df = df[df['date']!= latestDate]
```

How do I loop the code above until the len of rows for max date is not 1.
How do you a descending for loop date range?

Comment: The max_date explanation is not comprehensible - please specify in clear terms what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi i've edited and defined the max date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `groupby` and `transform`

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df_filtered = df[(df.groupby('date')['names'].transform('count')!=1) | (df['date'].dt.year != 2022)]
```

|  | date | names | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-04-01 | john | 15 |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 | jane | 15 |
| 2 | 2022-04-01 | Swansa | 15 |
| 3 | 2022-04-02 | Timmy | 15 |
| 4 | 2022-04-02 | (null) | 15 |
| 5 | 2022-04-02 | (null) | 15 |

Comment: Hi sorry probably I didn't explain the entire situation clearly. The purpose why I am doing a descending for loop date here is that because data is appended daily to the dataframe, I am checking the last date if it's returned 1 row only, if so delete so that the append feature from a different function can continue appending based on the last date in the dataframe

Comment: I think in that case also this solution will work, can you test with your data and let me know?

Comment: this will work, however it might drop previous rows that matches that conditions for the previous year, the situation only apply for this year data only, that's why the for loop last date check.

Comment: added that condition